# Uninstalled libreoffice snap, files are now gone?

Tags: libreoffice

Recently uninstalled the snap version off Libre office and installed the .deb package. Now it seems that uninstalling the snap version also got rid off my saved files, how is this possible?

It seems the snap versions saves its files in /home/snap/libreoffice
and those folder got removed when removing the snap version this seems like a undesirable behavior?

Is there any way to recover this delete folders...?

Ubuntu 21.10
Libre office 7.2

So this is wath happened:

1. I installed libre office from the Ubuntu software store(snap version)
2. Created a couple off spreadsheets and saved them at the deafault? location witch i thought was somewhere in my home/documents, but it seems that the snap version store your files under /home/snap/libreoffice for some reason.
3. Realized that i wanted the deb version off libreoffice because it includes SVG icons by deafault and looks sharper on my hdpi monitor. So I went ahead and uninstalled the snap package and installed the deb version from the terminal(sudo apt install libreoffice) this worked fine.
4. I always open files by pressing super and start typing the name on the file i want to open but now this didn't return any of the files i recently created.

I have searched for the missing files with locate and foremost as suggested here but without any luck so it seems to my that the switch off office package somehow got rid of these files created whit the snap version. Its not the end of the day there weren't crazy import but I like to understand what went wrong.

/Oskar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)

Comment: snapd v2.39+ is supposed to save your data for 31 days (somewhere) until the next time you re-install.

Answer (score 0):

Removing an application *never* will remove your document files.

Even if you would misplace your document files in the configuration folders of applications you are removing, they would not be deleted. That is because user configuration files are not deleted upon uninstallation.

User configuration files are actually not placed there during installation. They are being created the first time the installed application runs. Uninstalling an application only will remove files installed in the system directories, not under the user's home directories.

So turn "Show hidden folders" on in the file manager, and start searching for your files. There is a good chance they are still there. If not, then *you* deleted them. Check your Trash first. In the worst case, the files are truly deleted, and then [attempts for data recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files) are your last chance for these files that did not yet make it to your backup.

Comment: I understand that this is how its supposed to work but somewhere in the switch from snap to deb package the files disappeared. I know for a fact that i did not delete them myself, however i might have saved them in a "bad place". But still its the default directory when you press save in the snap version off libre office.

Comment: That your files disappeared with absolute certainly is not due to the installation process itself. That is the message I wanted to convey. Something else happened. I cannot know what. Snap version of LO also will save in your normal home directory - the connection is enabled. Even then, removing the snap will not remove files under /home/snap/libreoffice